# UIImage return Null IOS

Tags: ios

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
              pictureUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];  
NSLog(@"image width:%@",image.size.width);
```

I am getting null from this log? The image is valid and displaying correctly?.
This is in a table cell

Comment: where is your image file, in the application bundle or not?

Comment: Image size is a float value. so change %@ to %f. But I wonder you are not getting any crash after u are trying to print the float value to string value

Comment: @Anish There is no reason to get a crash here, just undefined behavior. The string format indicator just lets the OS know how to treat the bits that it gets from memory - you could just try and print out data representing float bits as a string with no special problem.

Comment: @Stavash: sometimes when i try to print a int value to string(by mistake), i get an exception. i thought this could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"image width:%f",image.size.width);
```

Besides that, I hope you are calling this on a background thread (**not** within cellForRow), otherwise loading your cells will be very slow and screw up user interaction.